# Como pegar o valor de um select option e popular dentro de uma variavel no jsp

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

Gostaria de saber como eu faço para pegar o valor de select option e inputo dentro de ma variavel no jsp.
Estou tentando o seguinte codigo mais esta dando erro :

Aqui eu preencho o select com dados que vem do banco.

```
<select id="STR_MAC" style="width: 600px;" name="STR_MAC" onchange="update()">

                        <%
                            String qry_types2 = "SELECT DISTINCT MACROTECNOLOGIA FROM EPE_VW_PRT_MAPE_ALLOC ORDER BY MACROTECNOLOGIA";
                        ResultSet rsSTR_MAC = stm.executeQuery(qry_types2);

                        while (rsSTR_MAC.next()) {
                            if (rsSTR_MAC.getString("MACROTECNOLOGIA").equals(request.getParameter("STR_MAC"))) {
                                out.println("<option value='" + rsSTR_MAC.getString("MACROTECNOLOGIA") + "' selected=true>"
                                + rsSTR_MAC.getString("MACROTECNOLOGIA") + "</option>");
                            } else {
                                out.println("<option value='" + rsSTR_MAC.getString("MACROTECNOLOGIA") + "' >"
                                + rsSTR_MAC.getString("MACROTECNOLOGIA") + "</option>");
                            }
                        }
                        rsSTR_MAC.close();
                        %>
                    </select>
```

E aqui é onde eu estou tentando passar o valor do select option para minha variavel porem neste trecho esta dando erro.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <% 
    String STR_MAC = new String();
    
        function update() {
            var select = document.getElementById('STR_MAC');
            var text = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
            console.log(text);
        }
        update();
        
        STR_MAC = text;
        
        System.out.println("Esse eu peguei da tela : " + STR_MAC);
        %>
    </script>
```

Aqui segue o erro que esta sendo gerado em minha pagina :

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 161 in the jsp file: /kpi/chart_people_knowledge_risk.jsp
Syntax error on token "function", new expected
158:    <% 
159:    String STR_MAC = new String();
160:    
161:        function update() {
162:            var select = document.getElementById('STR_MAC');
163:            var text = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
164:            console.log(text);
```

Obrigado a todos e agradeço a atenção desde já.

Answer (score 0):

Você está misturando JSP com javascript;

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function update() {
        var select = document.getElementById('STR_MAC');
        var text = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
        console.log(text);
    }
    update();
</script>
```

Até onde eu me recordo, você não consegue passar uma variável javascript para scriptlet, logo o código abaixo não vai funcionar;

```
STR_MAC = text;
    
    System.out.println("Esse eu peguei da tela : " + STR_MAC);
```

Comment: E neste caso como eu poderia pegar esse valor do select option e passar para uma variavel jsp ?

Comment: No onchange faz uma requisição usando fetch api passando o valor, assim você consegue pegar.